# How to add nonce in style and script src

Tags: angular, webpack, angular5, content-security-policy

I want add nonce in the style and script src to work with strict CSP.
How can I add nonce through webpack?

Following are my application configurations.

Following are my application configurations:
    Angular CLI: 1.6.3
    Node: 6.14.1
    OS: linux x64
    Angular: 5.2.0

Comment: After searching I found that nonce can be added by putting

  __webpack_nonce__ = 'c29tZSBjb29sIHN0cmluZyB3aWxsIHBvcCB1cCAxMjM=';

at the entry file, but it is also not working as expected. Please provide some solution for this.

Comment: There is no direct method to add nonce to dynamic style tags in angular-cli. So we are putting unsafe-inline for style-src.

Comment: where is this entry file ? I need nonce for script tags in with angular-cli